# How to install intervention/image in laravel 6

Tags: laravel, intervention

I have tried to get solution from others in stackoverflow but no one is working. I have installed Laravel in my cpanel. My folder structure is www.mysite.com/home. I have created a php.ini file in file manager with this code

> extension=php_fileinfo.dll

Still it's showing this message in ssh panel.

[image]

Comment: `.dll`s are for Windows, `/opt/alt/php72/...` sounds like Linux

Comment: Don't post text as image

Answer (score 0):

If you use the default `php.ini` you can uncomment this line. There should be no .dll line.

```
extension=fileinfo
```